# Apache mass virtual hosting & suexec & fcgid

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-fcgid, suexec

I followed [Falco's tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-11.10) and everything now works as expected for 2 users (e.g. john and alice) with their relevant directories (`/var/www/john` and `/var/ww/alice`).

Now, I want to go to the next level: instead of defining different vhosts at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<username>` and restarting Apache, I need dynamically configured mass virtual hosting (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html).
Say, my DNS server has records for: `another.site.example.com`, I want it's home directory to be at `/var/www/another.site/web`.

The problem is all these configuration settings for suexec and mod_fcgid.
I ended to this draft of my `httpd.conf` (or should I create a file like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mass_virtual` ?):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#default virtual host
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/root/web/

  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    SuexecUserGroup web-admin web-admin
    <Directory /var/www/root/web/>
      Options +ExecCGI
      Options -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/root/php-fcgi-starter .php
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>

#3rd-level subdomain virtual hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  #problematic email!
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  #is this /var/www/another.site/web or /var/www/www.another.site/web for
  #a request for www.another.site.example.com ?
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3+/web

  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    #problematic group and user!
    SuexecUserGroup web1 web1
    <Directory /var/www/*/web/>
      Options +ExecCGI
      Options -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/*/php-fcgi-starter .php
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

1. As you can see from the comments I have a problematic `ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com`, a `SuexecUserGroup web1 web1` and a `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3+/web` configuration!
2. Moreover, to ensure security I think `IfModule` shouldn't exist-if
   `mod_fcgid` can't load then neither should the server and,
3. instead of `Alow from all`, I think I should have `Deny from all` and open-up a
   php-library directory instead!
4. As I said, my intention is a request for www.another.site.example.com to be directed to user at /var/www/another.site/web but as I've read at "[Using suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html)" we can call suexec without the SuexecUserGroup directive in VirtualHost definitions but with the help of mod_userdir! So, what if a request for `www.another.site.example.com` is transformed transparently to `www.example.com/~another.site` with the help of mod_rewrite and then use mod_userdir to enable suexec???

Any ideas or directives that implement all these?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49439 but as Witold Baryluk proposes I have to patch mod_suexec of Apache server! So, I still need some instructions for patching...!

Answer (score 2):

in practice the dynamic vhost feature is not optimal, because you
are not flexible enough (.htaccess is in some cases not enough).
use a script to generate the vhosts or use something like puppet to define
the vhosts (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache).

btw: for your php setup i would use php-fpm (ondemand) with (mod_proxy_fcgi or mod_fastcgi).
with php-fpm you don't need suexec - every user gets his own port or socket.